# Obtain Web.config log4net section parameter

Tags: vb.net, parameters, log4net-configuration, configurationsection, log4net-appender

I have an application which uses **log4net** for logging messages. In the **web.config** there is a section which looks like this:

```
<log4net>
   <appender name="smth" type="smthType">
     <file value="name.log" />
   </appender>
</log4net>
```

My question is: **how can I get the value `name.log` from this section?**

I tried this:

```
Dim section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("log4net")
```

but since the value is in the `appender` section, I am not sure how to get it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you need that value? Are you trying to extend log4net?

Comment: I don't want to extend log4net, I just need the name of the log file, because I want to perform some operations on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that, instead of reading from web.config, you should use the log4net API, for example:

```
Dim appender as IAppender = LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders()[0];
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution.